# How do you use .subcribe() data being to passed to a child component in Angular

Tags: angular

I am under the assumption that when you do a .subscribe() call you can then use the returned data to link to your HTML page. Is it possible to send that returned data to the child and/or parent component? If so, is it all async?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Input/Output to communicate data between the components. Need more info to help you precisely. But you can check the documentation: https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs